# What is the difference between kde plot in seaborn and distplot in plotly? Also, are KDE plots reliable if the dataset is imbalanced?

Tags: python, plotly, seaborn, kde-plasma, kernel-density

I'm trying to figure out the difference between KDE plots in seaborn and distplot in plotly. While I understand that both try to estimate the underlying distribution of the data, I'm not sure how exactly.

For instance, I tried plotting the kde plot and dist plot of two variables from the same dataset.

This is the kde plot using `seaborn`:

[image]

and this is the dist plot using `plotly`:

[image]

What is the difference between these 2 graphs and how would be interpret them.
Also, can KDE plots be used in an imbalanced dataset( i.e. there are 2 categories of the dependent variable and number of datapoints under each category differ largely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the two plots don't look the same is that you are passing the entire data set to `sns.kdeplot` and seaborn understands that there are two categories and that the area under the both curves combined together must sum to 1.

When you pass two separate curves to `ff.create_distplot` in plotly, the area under each curve individually sums to 1.

If you were to use the same code to plot an imbalanced dataset where the class imbalance is 90-10 for example, the minority category in the kde plot in seaborn would appear like a flat line with near 0 density, whereas the distplot in plotly would consider the two categories separately from one another so you might not know that you were viewing an imbalanced data set.

Comment: So if we're trying to compare the distribution of the 2 categories, we should compare their individual curves( such that area under each equals 1), right?

Comment: @swastika if there's a large imbalance between the two categories, yes – you'll want to compare their individual curves so that the distributions are clear